# ZF2 - Doctrine - Empty value in nested Fieldset results in A new entity was found

Tags: php, forms, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine

I have a Doctrine Entity Product with a nullable relationship to Supplier.

The FieldSets are nested. If I leave the field for Supplier empty the Doctrine Hydrator returns: A new entity was found through the relationship.

Product:

```
    /**
     * @var \Entities\Supplier
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Entities\Supplier")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="supplier_id", referencedColumnName="id",  nullable=true)
     * })
     */
     private $supplier;
```

FieldSet:

```
    /**
     * Constructor for Cms\Form\SupplierFieldSet.
     * 
     * @param ObjectManager $objectManager
     */
     public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
     {
        parent::__construct('supplier');

        $this->setObjectManager($objectManager);
        $this->setHydrator(new    DoctrineEntity($this->getObjectManager()))->setObject(new Supplier());

       $this->addElements();
     }
```

View:

```
    <?php
    $form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('product', array('action' => 'add')));
    $form->setAttribute('class', 'form-horizontal');

    $form->prepare();
    echo $this->form()->openTag($form);

    $product = $form->get('product');
    $supplier = $product->get('supplier');
    ?>

    <div class="form-group <?= ($this->formElementErrors($supplier->get('name'))) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
        <?php echo $this->formHidden($supplier->get('id')); ?>
        <?php
        echo $this->formRow($supplier->get('name')) . PHP_EOL;
        ?>
     </div>
```

I don't want the Hydrator to try and persist a Supplier if no value has been given. The database doesn't require for the related entity to be available.

What can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You say you pass an empty value, but in your `SupplierFieldSet` constructor you pass a `new Supplier()`. A new entity is not the same as an empty value...

When you create a new instance of supplier doctrine's unit of work sees this new entity, but since the association is not set to cascade persist it trows an exception.

You can either decide not to pass a `new Supplier()` or you can add `cascade={"persist"}` to your relation ship to make this work like this:

```
/**
 * @var \Entities\Supplier
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Entities\Supplier", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="supplier_id", referencedColumnName="id",  nullable=true)
 * })
 */
 private $supplier;
```

Comment: Hello Wilt, I don want a cascade persist. The problem is that an empty array is passed as one of the values. If I set those values to NULL it works. You say don't pass a new Supplier. What is the alternative then?

Comment: I have not much experience with these forms but you should possibly set field as not required and make sure that if empty values are passed the association is not created... 
I wonder if you don't add cascade persist how it should ever work if you do pass a supplier. Or are suppliers already in the database?

Comment: Suppliers are already in the database it should only add a relationship if one is given. but if empty it should do nothing.

Comment: @Antenne What happens if you do: `$this->setHydrator(new DoctrineObject($this->getObjectManager())`;

Comment: Exactly the same A new entity was found through the relationship 'Entities\Product#supplier'. I tried implementing a Null filter, but to no avail.

Comment: Maybe the [`DoctrineObject` documentation on form and fieldset](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/hydrator.md#the-fieldsets) can help you solve your issue. I would guess the problem lies somewhere in your configuration...